# What is this javascript syntax where you have () around the whole variable expression?

Tags: javascript

```js
({ body: { customer } } = await callCreateCustomer({
    email: createRandomEmailAddress(),
    key: 999,
    password: 'password',
}));
```

I don't understand what it means when you have `()` around the whole expression?

What does it do?

Comment: It's using *destructuring* to assign parts of the return value to the existing identifiers body and customer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Might be worth pointing out, only customer gets destructed..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is *Destructuring Assignment without declaration*. Here `customer` variable is already declared above and a value is being assigned with `response.body.customer`

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration):

> The parentheses ( ... ) around the assignment statement are required when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> `{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the {a, b} on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, `({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2})` is valid, as is `var {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}`
>
> Your ( ... ) expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.

Answer (score 6):

It forces expression context so that the first `{` is not treated as the start of a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

Comment: Does this have a name?, if not I have an idea -> `ambiguity resolver`  :)